# Sorl-thumbnail bugs 502 with large image

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

An error **502 Bad Gateway** when I try to show in template large image (more then 2000x2000px) with **Sorl-Thumbnail**.

No mistake if load page without thumbnail just picture and if less then 20000x2000px

Already tried to change nginx config like this...:

```
server {
    proxy_connect_timeout       1500;
    proxy_send_timeout          1500;
    proxy_read_timeout          1500;
    send_timeout                1500;
    location / {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1500;
    }
}
```

Use regular code in template like

```
{% thumbnail ph.image "500x500" crop="center" format="PNG" as im %}
<img src="{{ im.url }}"/>
{% endthumbnail %}
```

Any advise pls?

*Just for google search* 
Django Python Sorl-Thumbnail Thumbnail 502 Bad Gateway large image

Comment: If you're using gunicorn try adding to the conf file 
`timeout=600
keepalive=600` 
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#timeout
Update Supervisor also: `supervisorctl update`

Comment: @alfredo138923 
I added --timeout 600 --keep-alive 600, nothing happens.
Is supervisorctl nessesary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend helped me with this problem. The *Pil* bugs!

There is a thing like [Engine](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/settings.html?highlight=engine) in *Sorl-Thumbnail*. Default is *Pil*

```
'sorl.thumbnail.engines.pil_engine.Engine'
```

and it bugs with large images.
So it is better to use something another like

*Pgmagick, ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick or Wand*

We chosed *ImageMagick*. In *settings.py* add

```
THUMBNAIL_ENGINE = 'sorl.thumbnail.engines.convert_engine.Engine'
```

and install it by

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

And possibly it will be necessary to increate time for image resize processing in gunicorn by this command

```
--timeout 600
```

Also possibly server just does not have enough RAM. I used a server with 512 mb RAM. With simple site. (no wasting RAM...)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Hola! This saved a lot of time. actually i thinkl sorl have to document about different thumbnail engine seperately! no!!